# iPhone: UIBarButtonItem as first responder?

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, becomefirstresponder

Is it only classes inheriting from `UIControl` that can become "first responder"? 
I need a button in the navigation bar that brings up a `UIPickerView` using the `inputView/inputAccessoryView` properties. I know that I can use the `customView` property of the `UIBarButtonItem` and create a custom `UIButton`, but this would need "Photo Shopping" to create an image similar to the `UIBarButtonItem` "Done" style button (which is what I want).

Any suggestions how/if I can get `UIBarButtonItem` to become first responder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically any class which inherits from UIResponder (not just UIControl, but also UIView subclasses) can become first responders, but UIBarButtonItem inherits from UIBarItem and NSObject.  Hence it can not become the first responder.

Out of curiosity, what you are doing is not possible by just displaying the UIPickerView on a button press?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I just wanted to use a tool bar on top of the picker using the inputAccessoryView property. I think I'll go for a custom UIButton solution then.